# Batch File for Counting Characters in Filenames

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I'm pretty new to creating batch files (and programming in general) and was wanting to ask for some help regarding this task. I'm needing to create a batch file that I can drop into a network folder and run in order to count up all of the characters of each PDF, TIF, and TIFF filename that it comes across. I'd like to have it search through the directory that it is run from as well as any subfolders within and then return with the total count at the end.

So far it counts each file out but I would like to adjust it to exclude special characters (mostly underscores) from the character count. I also have not been able to successfully get it to give me a total count at the end. I've managed to successfully change a few things while researching tutorials online but I'm now unfortunately at a point where I've run out of tinkering time. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
PUSHD %~dp0
FOR /R %%G in (*.PDF *.TIF *.TIFF) DO (
 SET FileName=%%~nG
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 FOR /l %%L IN (2048,-1,0) DO IF NOT DEFINED CH (
 SET CH=!FileName:~%%L,1!
 IF DEFINED CH SET /a CH=1+%%L & ECHO !FileName!: !CH! Characters
 )
 ENDLOCAL
)
POPD
ECHO:
ECHO Total Number of Characters: %Total%
REM Not yet sure where to put Set /a Total=%Total%+%CH%
ECHO:
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

EDIT: For anyone else that may stumble upon this thread. I wasn't able to figure out how to fully accomplish this with Batch but I was able to do so in PowerShell. Here is the PS script I came up with.

```
# This script looks through all folders and subfolders that are sitting next to or below the powershell file. It gives the total file and character count of all PDFs, TIFFs, and TIFs that it finds.

# Clear all default PowerShell messages and remove from view.
Clear-Host


# Make the view more orderly.
Write-Output "" "---Processing Files---" ""


# Look through the current directory and all sub-folders for the names of .pdfs, .tifs, and .tiffs and show them as a list.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name -Include *.pdf,*.tif,*.tiff


# Get the total number of files.
$LineCount = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name -Include *.pdf,*.tif,*.tiff | Measure-Object -Line).Lines

# Set ChracterCount to the complete list of files and select ONLY the name portion so that no folder names are shown.
$CharacterCount = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.pdf,*.tif,*.tiff | Select -ExpandProperty Name)

# Replace all of the extensions and underscores in the filenames with nothing so that we only have the characters that were manually typed by someone.
$CharacterCount = $CharacterCount -Replace ".pdf","" -Replace ".tiff","" -Replace ".tif","" -Replace "_",""

# Gives us the final character count as a single number.
$CharacterCount = ($CharacterCount | Measure-Object -Character).Characters


# Show the viewer the final counts.
Write-Output "" "---All Files Processed---" "" "" "Total File Count: $LineCount" "" "" "Total Character Count: $CharacterCount" "" ""


# Gives the final closing message to the viewer so that they can exit with any key. Does not show message when script is run from ISE.
if ($Host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost")
{
    Write-Host "Press Any Key to Exit."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
}
```

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type: `for /?`. Read the last section about the command modifiers.  You will most likely want to use `%%~nG` for the file name only.  Also read about the `/R` option.

Comment: What are you expecting `IF NOT DEFINED ch (IF DEFINED ch <Do Stuff>)` to do? _If `ch` is not defined <do what is in the parentheses>, but if 'what is in the parentheses' is only relevant to `ch` being defined, nothing should happen!_

Comment: @Compo That was one of the parts that was already included in the script that I copied this from. Not sure why they put it in like that but it works so I left it as is. If it's pointless I don't mind removing it.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks very much for the tip. I took a look at it and was successfully able to solve two of my problems with them. The script now handles subfolders and also excludes the extensions from the character count. I went ahead and updated the code on the OP to reflect the changes. I'm still in need of a total character count at the end and I'd like to remove any special characters or at least underscores from the count as well if that is possible. I'm just not sure where to add something like Set /a Total=%Total%+%CH%. I've tried several locations and none seem to work. Any suggestions?